# React Hooks Dependencies - Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
import React from "react";

export const useFetch = (promise, args = [], options = {}) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loading: false,
    data: null,
    error: null
  });

  if (!args) args = [];

  const fetch = React.useCallback((...args) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      loading: true,
      error: null
    });

    return promise(...args)
      .then(response => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          data: response
        });
        return response;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error
        });
      });
  }, [promise, state]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (options.now) {
      fetch(...args);
    }
  }, [args, fetch, options.now]);

  return {
    fetch,
    ...state
  };
};
```

But **I'm getting an infinite console.log loop** when I try to use like this:

```
const allUsers = () => Promise.resolve([{ name: 'Bruno' }])

function App() {
  const { data } = useFetch(allUsers, [], { now: true })
  console.log('->', data)
  return (
    <span>Testing hook</span>
  )
}
```

All the deps and the useCallback was suggestions from the lint react-hooks/exhaustive-deps. So, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the purpose of this custom hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems.
1. Your fetch is getting a new value every time as it has state as a dependency and that is causing useEffect run every time, so infinite loop.
2.useEffect has args as a dependency which is also not the same every time, you don't need to pass args to fetch as it's already available because of closure.

here is an updated code that doesn't go in an infinite loop. you might get lint issue but you should ignore them for now until this linter becomes more standard.

```
const useFetch = (promise, args = [], options = {}) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loading: false,
    data: null,
    error: null
  });

  if (!args) args = [];

  const fetch = React.useCallback(() => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      loading: true,
      error: null
    });

    return promise(...args)
      .then(response => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          data: response
        });
        return response;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error
        });
      });
  }, [promise]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (options.now) {
      fetch();
    }
  }, [fetch, options.now]);

  return {
    fetch,
    ...state
  };
};

const allUsers = () => Promise.resolve([{ name: 'Bruno' }])


const App = props => {
  const { data } = useFetch(allUsers, [], { now: true });
  console.log(data, "=>");
  return <input name="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />;
}
```