# react hooks (useEffect) infinite loop clarification

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634206/react-hook-useeffect-infinite-loop-despite-dependency-list?noredirect=1#comment101721659_57634206) previous question of mine. I have written two custom hooks. The first is `useFetchAccounts` whose job is to fetch some data about user accounts and looks like this:

```
// a fake fetch for the sake of the example
function my_fetch(f, delay) {
  setTimeout(f, delay)
}

function useFetchAccounts() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({accounts: [], loaded: false})

  useEffect(() => {
    my_fetch(() => {setData({accounts: [{id:1},{id:2}], loaded: true})}, 3000)
  }, [])

  return data
}
```

Nothing special about this hook, simply fetches the ids of the accounts.

Now I have another hook, `useFetchBalancesWithIDs(account_ids, accounts_loaded)`, which is meant to take the ids from the previous step and fetch the balances of these accounts if the accounts have been loaded. It looks like this:

```
function useFetchBalanceWithIDs(account_ids, accounts_loaded) {

  const [balances, setBalances] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!accounts_loaded) return; // only fetch if accounts are loaded
    my_fetch(() => {
      setBalances(account_ids.map(id => 42+id))
    }, 3000)
  }, [account_ids, accounts_loaded])

  return balances
}
```

As you can see if the `accounts_loaded` is false, it will not perform the fetch. Together I am using them as follows:

```
function App() {

  const account_data = useFetchAccounts()

  const accounts = account_data.accounts
  const account_ids = accounts.map(account => account.id) // extract ids

  const balance = useFetchBalanceWithIDs(account_ids, account_data.loaded)

  console.log(balance)

  return null
}
```

Unfortunately, this results in an infinite loop. What does work is changing the `useFetchBalancesWithIDs` to this:

```
function useFetchBalanceWithAccounts(accounts, accounts_loaded) {

  const [balances, setBalances] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!accounts_loaded) return; // only fetch if accounts are loaded
    my_fetch(() => {
      setBalances(accounts.map(account => 42+account.id))
    }, 3000)
  }, [accounts, accounts_loaded])

  return balances
}
```

which performs the ids extraction within. I'm using it like this:

```
function App() {

  const account_data = useFetchAccounts()

  const accounts = account_data.accounts

  const balance = useFetchBalanceWithAccounts(accounts, account_data.loaded)

  console.log(balance)

  return null
}
```

which runs just fine. So the problem seems to be related to the extraction of the IDs from within the App component, which seems to be triggering the `useFetchBalanceWithIDs` all the time, even though the `account_ids` do not change value. Can someone help explain this behaviour please? It's OK for me to use `useFetchBalanceWithAccounts` but I would like to understand why `useFetchBalanceWithIDs` doens't work. Thank you!

Comment: You pass account id's to `useFetchBalancesWithIDs` using `data.accounts.map(x=>x.id)`? If this is the case then even though the data didn't change the id's did because `[1,2,3]` does not equal `[1,2,3]` (referential equality). You can memoize extracting the ids. with [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referential equality is used by `useEffect`, that means that `[1,2,3]` would not equal `[1,2,3]`

```
const data = [{id:1}];
data.map(d=>d.id)===data.map(d=>d.id);//is false
```

One way to prevent the array from id's from changing reference is combining useState with useEffect in App:

```
function App() {
  //store account id's in app state
  const [accountIds, setAccountIds] = useState([]);
  const account_data = useFetchAccounts();
  const accounts = account_data.accounts;
  //only if accounts change re set the id's
  useEffect(() => {
    setAccountIds(accounts.map(a => a.id));
  }, [accounts]);
  const balance = useFetchBalanceWithAccounts(
    accountIds,
    account_data.loaded
  );
  console.log(balance);
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're using the map function to get an array of your account ids. React uses Object.is to determine if your values in the dependency array has changed in each render cycle. The map function returns a new array, so even though the values in your array are the same, the comparison check evaluates to false, and the effect is run.